# Why can't I read the contents of my ArrayList in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I am reading data from a Firestore database in my Android activity and storing the data in an `ArrayList` but when I print out the `ArrayList` I get the last entry printed out and none of the other entries.

Here is my Kotlin code:

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counties)

        var sites : ArrayList<Site> = ArrayList<Site>()
        var site : Site = Site()

        val selectedCounty: String = intent.getStringExtra("COUNTY")

        sites.clear()

        db.collection("UKSites")
            .document("England")
            .collection("Counties")
            .document(selectedCounty)
            .collection(selectedCounty)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                for (document in documents) {

                    site.name = document.data["Name"].toString()
                    site.address?.line1 = document.data["Address Line 1"].toString()
                    site.address?.line2 = document.data["Address Line 2"].toString()
                    site.address?.line3 = document.data["Address Line 3"].toString()
                    site.address?.line4 = document.data["Address Line 4"].toString()
                    site.address?.postcode = document.data["Postcode"].toString()
                    site.address?.phoneNumber = document.data["Telephone"].toString()
                    site.address?.siteURL = document.data["Site URL"].toString()
                    site.description = document.data["Description"].toString()
                    site.price = document.data["Price"] as Double
                    site.distance = 0
                    site.locationCoordinate?.Longitude = document.data["Longitude"] as Double
                    site.locationCoordinate?.Latitude = document.data["Latitude"] as Double

                    sites.add(site)

                    Log.i("Info","${sites.last().name}")

                }

                Log.i("Info", "${sites.size}")

                for ( nextSite in sites ) {
                    Log.i("Info", "site.name = ${nextSite.name}")
                }

                // Recycler View code here
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.w("Error", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
            }
```

And here is the output printed to the `Logcat` window:

```
    2020-01-18 15:22:14.376 10629-10658/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk D/FA:   Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto,   ga_previous_class(_pc)=CountriesActivity,  ga_previous_id(_pi)=-7126357891560843792,  ga_screen_class(_sc)=CountiesActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-7126357891560843791}]
    2020-01-18 15:22:14.396 10629-10629/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk  I/Info: Stroud Farm
    2020-01-18 15:22:14.399 10629-10629/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: Bennets Wood Farm
    2020-01-18 15:22:14.401 10629-10629/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: Bluebell Farm
    2020-01-18 15:22:14.404 10629-10629/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: Pinecopse Kennels
    2020-01-18 15:22:14.407 10629-10629/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: Pinecopse Kennels
    2020-01-18 15:22:14.410 10629-10629/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: Bennets Wood Farm
    2020-01-18 15:22:14.414 10629-10629/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: Bluebell Farm
    2020-01-18 15:22:14.416 10629-10629/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: Stroud Farm
    2020-01-18 15:13:20.486 10221-10221/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: 8
    2020-01-18 15:13:20.486 10221-10221/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: site.name = Stroud Farm
    2020-01-18 15:13:20.486 10221-10221/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: site.name = Stroud Farm
    2020-01-18 15:13:20.486 10221-10221/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: site.name = Stroud Farm
    2020-01-18 15:13:20.486 10221-10221/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: site.name = Stroud Farm
    2020-01-18 15:13:20.486 10221-10221/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: site.name = Stroud Farm
    2020-01-18 15:13:20.486 10221-10221/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: site.name = Stroud Farm
    2020-01-18 15:13:20.486 10221-10221/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: site.name = Stroud Farm
    2020-01-18 15:13:20.487 10221-10221/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk I/Info: site.name = Stroud Farm
    2020-01-18 15:13:20.502 10221-10252/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk D/EGL_emulation:     eglMakeCurrent: 0xae085060: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xae083400)
    2020-01-18 15:13:20.524 10221-10252/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae085060: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xae083400)
    2020-01-18 15:13:20.578 10221-10252/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae085060: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xae083400)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an object of `Site` only once. So while using in the loop, you are just resetting values of same object again and again. This is the reason you are getting the value of the last element from the loop.

You need to create the object each time. So `var site : Site = Site()` must be inside for-each loop. As below

```
for (document in documents) {
   // Create object here
   var site : Site = Site()
   // Then do your tasks what is currently doing
   site.name = document.data["Name"].toString()
   ....

}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working now but can you explain why that works?

Comment: why is not possible to change the `name` property, for example, of the same object `site` in the `for` loop?

Comment: `val site` is enough, not `var`. `site` reference isn't changed within a loop iteration

Comment: @Onik what do you mean?